# Is there an optimal solution for this?

Tags: python

I have a large data that contains: ID,year,program. I want to filter out IDs if a particular program say A, has more value of year(example : 2019>2018) than another program say B. I have a solution but that involves a loop. I want to know if there's another way of doing this.
My code :

```
unique = list(set(finalAD['ID']))
IDFiltered = []
for i in unique:
    data = finalAD[finalAD['ID'] == i]
    AD1 = data[data['Program'].str.match('AD')]
    ind = list(AD1.index.values)
    AD2 = data.drop(ind)
    date1 = AD1['Year'].max()
    date2 = AD2['Year'].min()
    if(date2 > date1):
        IDFiltered.append(i)

newData = finalAD[finalAD['ID'].isin(IDFiltered)]
newData.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
newData.head()
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/ is extremely good at this sort of thing...

Comment: passing to pandas like hiro said is a good solution and compatible one

Comment: or you can try to run with threads due to your result return to a list `IDFiltered` to speed up the loops by parallel execution